# Laravel data not being displayed

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query, laravel-8

I am trying to read data from a local collections from my mongodb database. Name of database Intuit name of collection post.
Code inside PostController:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;
class PostController extends Controller{

public function home() {
    $posts = Post::with(['user'])->get();

    return view('home', ['posts' => $posts->toArray()]);
}}
```

Code inside Post:

```
class Post extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
'STATUS',

'DDC_CODE',

'TRADE_NAME',

'SCIENTIFIC_CODE',

'SCIENTIFIC_NAME',

'INGREDIENT_STRENGTH',

'DOSAGE_FORM_PACKAGE',

'ROUTE_OF_ADMIN',
'PACKAGE_PRICE',

'GRANULAR_UNIT',

'MANUFACTURER',

'REGISTERED_OWNER',

'UPDATED_DATE',

'SOURCE'
];}
```

All of the above are the titles of the columns in the table.
Next home.blade.php:

```html
<!DOCTPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "1">
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>STATUS</td>
<td>DDC_CODE</td>
<td>TRADE_NAME</td>
<td>SCIENTIFIC_CODE</td>
<td>SCIENTIFIC_NAME</td>
<td>SCIENTIFIC_CODE</td>
<td>INGREDIENT_STRENGTH</td>
<td>DOSAGE_FORM_PACKAGE</td>
<td>ROUTE_OF_ADMIN</td>
<td>PACKAGE_PRICE</td>
<td>GRANULAR_UNIT</td>
<td>MANUFACTURER</td>
<td>UPDATED_DATE</td>
<td>SOURCE</td>

</tr>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<tr>
<td>{{ $post->_id }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->STATUS }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->DDC_CODE }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->TRADE_NAME }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->SCIENTIFIC_CODE }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->SCIENTIFIC_NAME }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->INGREDIENT_STRENGTH }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->DOSAGE_FORM_PACKAGE }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->ROUTE_OF_ADMIN }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->PACKAGE_PRICE }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->GRANULAR_UNIT }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->MANUFACTURER }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->REGISTERED_OWNER }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->UPDATED_DATE }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->SOURCE }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The route handler is as follows

```
Route::get('view','App\Http\Controllers\PostController@home');
```

all of this seems to be fine but when I load up the application I see nothing but the column titles not sure what I am missing, I believe it is not working because the query in PostController is incorrect and need to change it as it is taken from another projec. Any and all help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: do you have posts in your database ? what `post::with(['user'])->count()` returns ?

Comment: Yeah I do I can see it using the mongodb compass and also I made the collection

Comment: Your model is `Post`, not `post`. `dd($posts);` right after `$posts = ...` in your method

Comment: @brombeer when I change the post to Post the output does not change also when do the dd($posts) I get Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1241 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

Comment: Does `dd(Post::all());` return anything? Do you have debugging turned on? Do you `use` the model? Can you post your complete controller? Is your db-connection working, have you successfully retrieved/saved data from/to it?

Comment: I have edited the post to show all of the controller and where should I put the dd(Post::all()); @brombeer

Comment: First line in your `home()` method

Comment: I think there is a possibility that the controller is not able to connect to the collection is there any way to check that it is actually connected?

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1240 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}` is what I get when I do `dd(Post::all());`

Comment: Have you defined ```user``` relation in your post model?

Comment: No I do not what do I do instead there?

Comment: @AnshulRaj If you don't have ```user``` relation defined in the ```Post``` model, then why are you querying it through ```->with(['user'])``` method? Check this out https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Post::with(['user'])->get();
```

use

```
Post::with(['user'])->all();
```

subject to `user` relationship is properly defined in your `Post` model

Comment: What you are saying seems to have worked as I am getting no errors but it has completely crashed my vm on which I was testing is there any query to only get a small portion of the data and not all of it?

Comment: If you have huge set of data in DB, then it will occur. you have to use pagination. even get() would behave like this

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data as array, But you are trying to get them as object in your blade view file.

Instead of getting data like this:

```
$post->STATUS
```

Try using like this:

```
$post['STATUS']
```

Comment: I tried what you said but I am getting a syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' and it is highlighting the line I made the change at

Comment: Try this: remove toArray() function and just send $posts

Comment: Because the $posts itself is a collection. And you can get it's items using the syntax that you have done before in your blade view.

Comment: Ok so I tried removing the toArray and did the $post['STATUS'] and I got nothing but the column titles

Comment: Can you send more data ? A dd in your blade, like : dd($posts)

Comment: Yeah I tried a dd but It just returns null so I am assuming the collection is not being accessed

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `->toArray()`

Pass data as below & variables will get displayed

`return view('home', ['posts' => $posts)]);`

Comment: Tried this as well no changes still just the columns names and no data

Comment: `dd($posts->first())` check this in your `home` function, this will print out the first post, maybe you're not using attributes correctly

Comment: When I did this I am just getting a null So I guess the code is not accessing the collection?